# Javascript order of asynchronous execution

Tags: javascript

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I am looking for feedback on a specific scenario.

Let's say I have a page that contains the following code:

```
<script>
  var myCallback = function() {
      // stuff...
  }
</script>

<script async src="https://example.com/file.js?callback=myCallback"></script>

<script>
  var obj = {
    render: function() {
      this.funcA();
      this.funcB();
      this.funcC();
    },

    funcA: function() {
      // stuff
    },

    funcB: function() {
      // stuff
    },

    funcC: function() {
      // stuff
    }
  }

  obj.render();
</script>
```

The external script is set up to call 'myCallback' after it is loaded.

Is it possible that `myCallback` can be called while `obj.render()` is executing, or will it always wait until after `render` and all of its' subfunctions are called?

In other words, is it possible for `myCallback` to be called sometime in between the execution of `funcA`, `funcB`, and `funcC` or will it always wait until after they are all executed?

Comment: time to learn the event loop

Comment: That's what I'm asking. I think that as soon render is called then all of its sub functions would be added to the event loop, and therefore myCallback would be placed after them when the script returns. Is that right?

Comment: in the code you posted, `myCallback` would never be called at all

Comment: The external script calls that function after it is loaded. I should have specified that in the question.

Comment: yeah, I just cottoned on to that ...

Answer (score 0):

you cannot really tell when the asynch is completed. Most probably after obj.render() because it takes a while to initiate the asynchrone process. 
In the meanwhile the code for obj.render is processed. 
But depending on such a code flow seems like tricky business.
Let's hypothetical assume that the asynch code is loaded instantly because it is cached - then it might run before or while other parts of your code run.